# Create master switch to change all background colors

Tags: swift, class, switch-statement, overriding, call

I am looking to create a master switch that when it is turned off it changes the background color of every view controller class to red. I don't know if you can create a function to call the class that holds the switch. The switch will be in a different class but the background can also be change to red if necessary.

```
    import UIKit
    class Switch: UIViewController {
    var toggle = UISwitch()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(toggle)
        //set frame and other properties...

        toggle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleWasToggled(_:)), for: .allEvents)
          toggle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([

            toggle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :175),
            toggle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : 100),
            toggle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350),
            toggle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180),
            ])
    }

    @objc func toggleWasToggled(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        //Whenever the switch is toggled you can post a notification. You can even post two seperate notifications, one for when the toggle is on, and one for when it is off.
        NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ColorChange"), object: nil, userInfo: nil))

    }
    @objc func colorWasChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        print("espn")
    }
    }

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Add an observer in all your viewControllers that need to be notified of the color change.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(colorWasChanged(_:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ColorChange"), object: nil)
    }


    @objc func colorWasChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        print("cnn")
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a BaseViewController class and add observer and change color in this viewcontroller.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    static var switchStatus = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(colorChanged(_:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ColorChanged"), object: nil)
    }
    @objc func colorChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let switchStatus = notification.userInfo?["switchStatus"] as? Bool {
            BaseViewController.switchStatus = switchStatus
            if switchStatus {
                self.view.backgroundColor = .red
            } else {
                self.view.backgroundColor = .white
            }
        }
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if BaseViewController.switchStatus {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .red
        } else {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        }
    }
}
```

For all other viewcontrollers inherit from this viewcontroller. No need to add observer in each class. As it is inherited from BaseViewController it is automatically adds an observer for changing the color.

```
class ViewController: BaseViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Now when you change the value in UISwitch post a notification with the UISwitch status. Switch class is also inherited from BaseViewController.

```
class Switch: BaseViewController {
    var toggle = UISwitch()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(toggle)
        //set frame and other properties...
        toggle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleWasToggled(_:)), for: .allEvents)
    }
    @objc func toggleWasToggled(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        let userInfo = ["switchStatus":sender.isOn]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ColorChanged"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo))
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried the code I get the background color on the class with the switch to change colors but not any other classes. I have attached a link to my project for download if you could look at it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/kb0wmkw1iq1dm7o/talk.zip?dl=0

Comment: @sillymilly I've updated the BaseViewController class. Check updated answer

Comment: This works , I do have a question about what I would do if I wanted to use the switch to turn on off a avplayer. Each class plays a unique sound. I can't call the avplayer from a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Notifications for something like this. Here is an example:**

**Swift 5.0**

```
class Switch: UIViewController {
    var toggle = UISwitch()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(toggle)
        //set frame and other properties...

        toggle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleWasToggled(_:)), for: .allEvents)
    }

    @objc func toggleWasToggled(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        //Whenever the switch is toggled you can post a notification. You can even post two seperate notifications, one for when the toggle is on, and one for when it is off.
        NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ColorChange"), object: nil, userInfo: nil))
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Add an observer in all your viewControllers that need to be notified of the color change.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(colorWasChanged(_:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ColorChange"), object: nil)
    }

    //its important to also remove the observer when the viewController is no longer being displayed
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func colorWasChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        //Change color to red here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the uiswithc to class Switch. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to include the switch. Basically, whenever the switch is toggled on/off you can trigger a notification to post to all observing ViewControllers

Comment: I don't know what to put in  @objc func colorWasChanged(_ sender: Any) { in class view controller. I tried to put it in view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red but that does not do anything.

Comment: @A.Welch This won't work because you've removed the observer in viewDidDisappear

Comment: Can you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: I copied the code created two view controllers to place the classes and there is no effect when I change the switch.

Comment: @RajeshKumar could you try to answer.

Comment: @sillymilly delete NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

Comment: @RajeshKumarR That's all I have to do and it will work.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I have edited my question above with the suggested code. What is happening is it prints ESPN 3 times when the switch is changed in the log file. However there is no change on the background color of either class.